# gcov can't open source file while using it in Android AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, gcov, lcov, test-coverage

I have following AOSP project setup

1) I have test.cpp in *(AOSP root directory)/vendor/myProject/test.cpp*

2) In Android.mk i have used
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
   LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -lgcov

3) When I compile the code i get test.gcno in:
  (AOSP root directory)/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/myProject_intermediates

4) Then i put the test on device (adb sync)

5) Then on device i have used following:
    export GCOV_PREFIX=/vendor
    export GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=13 (to strip down the un-necessary path)

6) I run the test ./system/bin/test and i get test.gcda file on
   device (shell) /vendor/test.gcda

7) I copy the test.gcda (from device) to my build directory (/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/myProject_intermediates) where i already have test.gcno

8) Now i am in /out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/myProject_intermediates
Then run gcov as follows:

> (AOSP root
>   directory)/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcov
>   test

For this i get output as follows:

> File 'vendor/myProject/test.cpp' Lines executed:23.00% of 223
>
> vendor/myProject/test.cpp:creating 'test.cpp.gcov'
>
> vendor/myProject/test.cpp:cannot open source file

Can anybody help me on how to solve this. It says **test.cpp:cannot open source file**
gcov is not generating complete report. I have also checked -b option by specifying the path to source as follows:

> (AOSP root
>   directory)/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcov
>   -b (AOSP root directory)/vendor/myProject test

It didn't worked.

I guess the problem is because of distributed files (gcno,gcda,test.cpp) in different directories.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is while building the test in which directory you were, you should be in the same directory while running gcov later, then all the `.gcov` files will be created successfully.

For example:

Project directory : `android/frameworks/Myproj`
In this you have `test.cpp` and `Android.mk`

Then say suppose from android directory you'll build the `app` or `test.cpp`, i.e. `android$`

Then the `*.gcno` files will be present in `android/out/Myproj_Intermediates/`

You will get the `*.gcda` files by running `app` in device, you will bring that `*.gcda` files from device to folder `android/out/Myproj_intermediates/`

Now to run `gcov` on these:

You should be in the android directory (since you built app from there)

`android$ ./prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi-gcov \
          -o out/Myproj_intermediates/ -a frameworks/Myproj/test.cpp -b -c`

Comment: Note : i was running gcov after bringing *.gcda files from different directory not from android...so i was getting "can not open source file" Also running from "Intermediates" folder will not do..**Only from directory where you built the app (in eg: android)** running gcov works

Comment: @ user2438949 : Are you able to use lcov after successful gcov. I got geninfo: ERROR: GCOV failed for /home/user/AOSP/JB_emulatorBuild/out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/my_project_intermediates/test_project.gcda!

Comment: Running gcov from the same directory where gcc is run works on CentOS linux as well (none mobile OS)

Answer (score 0):

There has been a better approach in AOSP for several months now.

1. Add `LOCAL_NATIVE_COVERAGE := true` to your makefile.
2. `$ export NATIVE_COVERAGE := true`
3. Build, sync, run.
4. `$ acov`

`acov` will pull all the coverage files off the device, put them in the right place, and `lcov` (iirc this will prompt you to install if you don't already have it), and generate and HTML report for you.

Comment: Hey Dan.. I'm trying to generate code coverage for native components in aosp. Could you please point me to some git projects with sample or references ???

Comment: Try something like https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/README.md#gathering-test-coverage, but I think this all bitrot years ago. It didn't work last time I tried.